# Entity 'ContentDocumentLink' is not supported for semi join inner selects

Tags: apex, soql, contentdocumentlink

Why doesn't Salesforce support `semi join selects` on the `ContentDocumentLink` entity?

Why would there be a random entity that doesn't work like **all** the others?

---

This code:

```
List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = [SELECT VersionData 
                                        FROM ContentVersion 
                                        WHERE ContentDocumentId 
                                        IN (SELECT ContentDocumentId                                  
                                            FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                            WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId)
                                        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```

Throws this error:

> Entity 'ContentDocumentLink' is not supported for semi join inner selects

Comment: as a workaround:- Use this:- select VersionData from Contentversion where ContentDocumentId in (select id from ContentDocument)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some objects have an insanely high SOQL cost, so they're simply not allowed.

For example, you also can't do semi-join selects on `Task` or `Activity`, either because the performance cost is simply too great.

In those cases, you need to query one object, gather all the related ID values, then query the related object.

It's annoying, and rather useless most of the time, but it's there to prevent developers from querying potentially hundreds of tables.